# In this proof ( simplified version of Vieta's Theorem), do they use intercept form to prove it or am I just confused?

Tags: quadratics

[Picture of proof](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qr2Tz.jpg)

I was thinking that someone could give me some insight on this proof in general.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your questions (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Comment: Thank you for advice, next time I will do that.